# IsNumeric in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there an equivalent of IsNumeric in EF Core or by using linq or Dynamic Sql or similar?

I am trying to get only the rows with numeric values from a nvarchar column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Security Note: [Always use parameterization for raw SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters)

Given this dataset/result:

[image: dataset]

The entity class for EF Core: Sandbox.cs

```cs
    public class Sandbox
    {
        public int SandboxId { get; set; }
        public string StringOrNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Create a DbSet in your context:

```cs
    public DbSet<Sandbox> Sandboxes { get; set; }
```

Mark as no key:

```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sandbox>().HasNoKey();
```

Test:

```cs
    public async Task<IList<Sandbox>> GetNumberList()
    {
        // 1 = number, 0 = string
        var isNumeric = new SqlParameter("isNumeric", 1);

        var listOfNumbers = await _context.Sandboxes
        .FromSqlRaw("SELECT SandboxId, StringOrNumber FROM dbo.Sandbox WHERE ISNUMERIC(StringOrNumber) = @isNumeric", isNumeric)
        .ToListAsync();

        return listOfNumbers;
    }
```

An alternative to FromSqlRaw is [FromSqlInterpolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated?view=efcore-3.1).

```cs
    var listOfNumbers = await _context.Sandboxes
    .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT SandboxId, StringOrNumber FROM dbo.Sandbox WHERE ISNUMERIC(StringOrNumber) = {isNumeric}")
    .ToListAsync();
```

[image: Test Result]

Answer (score 4):

This has now been added to EF Core and it looks like it is part of EF Core 6.0 -  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23114

Answer (score 1):

[`ISNUMERIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function is part of EF Core 6.0 in [EF.Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.isnumeric?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions-isnumeric(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctions-system-string))

Answer (score 0):

Example of `IsNumeric` of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` 6.0+:

```
var query = DbContext.A_Entity.Where(i=>EF.Functions.IsNumeric(i.A_Property));
```