# Postgres FromSqlRaw Doesn't take params correctly

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core

**TL&DR:**

1. When I perform string interpolation OUTSIDE of FromSqlRaw, the  SQL Command works.
2. When I use SQLRAW and pass a variable, within the function. It no longer works, even though the documentation says it should.

Below is a **working** INSECURE method of performing string interpolation.

```
    [HttpGet("/home/dashboard/search")] 
    public async Task<ActionResult> dashboard_search([FromQuery] string search_string)
    {

    var query_string = $"select id, country_code, country_name, count(*) OVER() as total_count from ipaddresses where ipaddress::text LIKE '%{search_string}%' limit 8;";

    var results = await this._context.getDashboardSearchIpAddresses.FromSqlRaw(query_string).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(results);

    }
```

**This is however vulnerable to a SQL injection. <-- DON'T DO THIS !!!**

The Microsoft documentation says the following:

> FromSqlInterpolated is similar to FromSqlRaw but allows you to use
>   string interpolation syntax. Just like FromSqlRaw, FromSqlInterpolated
>   can only be used on query roots. As with the previous example, the
>   value is converted to a DbParameter and isn't vulnerable to SQL
>   injection.

When I try to use the FromSqlRaw i get an empty result set

```
    [HttpGet("/home/dashboard/search")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> dashboard_search([FromQuery] string search_string)
    {
        var results = await this._context.getDashboardSearchIpAddresses.FromSqlRaw("select id, country_code, country_name, count(*) OVER() as total_count from ipaddresses where ipaddress::text LIKE '%{0}%' limit 8;",search_string).ToListAsync(); 
return Ok(results); }
```

SEE Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: This is running in Postgres; This is a key issue as the below didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above is the 'correct' answer for all cases, except when using Postgres

```
  var searchParam = new NpgsqlParameter("searchParam", $"%{search_string}%");
  var results = await this._context.getDashboardSearchIpAddresses.FromSqlRaw("select id, split_part(text(ipaddress),'/',1) as ipaddress, country_code, country_name, count(*) OVER() as total_count from ipaddresses where ipaddress::text LIKE @searchParam limit 8;", searchParam).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry not in front of PC to test, maybe something like:

```
var searchParam = new SqlParameter("searchParam", search_string);
var results = await this._context.getDashboardSearchIpAddresses.FromSqlInterpolated($"select id, country_code, country_name, count(*) OVER() as total_count from ipaddresses where ipaddress::text LIKE %{searchParam}% limit 8").ToListAsync();
```

Or this using Raw:

```
var searchParam = new SqlParameter("searchParam", $"%{search_string}%");
var results = await this._context.getDashboardSearchIpAddresses.FromSqlRaw("select id, country_code, country_name, count(*) OVER() as total_count from ipaddresses where ipaddress::text LIKE @searchParam limit 8;",searchParam).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: End-to-end example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60942020/1657427).