# Why is NpgsqlParameter not working when passed to DbSet.FromSqlRaw

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-webapi, npgsql

As i mentioned in title, `DbSet.FromSqlRaw` not working when I pass `NpgsqlParameter`. I always get null.

Here are some variations i have tried:

```
long value = 3;
NpgsqlParameter npgsqlParameter = new NpgsqlParameter("value", value);
string query = "SELECT * FROM \"Admin\".\"User\" as usr WHERE \"usr\".\"Value\" = '@value'";

var _user = _AdminPanelDbContext
           .User
           .FromSqlRaw(query, npgsqlParameter)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

```
long value = 3;
NpgsqlParameter npgsqlParameter = new NpgsqlParameter("value", value);
string query = "SELECT * FROM \"Admin\".\"User\" as usr WHERE \"usr\".\"Value\" = ':value'";

var _user = _AdminPanelDbContext
           .User
           .FromSqlRaw(query, npgsqlParameter)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Before someone asks "Why don't you use inline interpolated strings?" like this.

```
FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM \"Admin\".\"User\" as usr WHERE \"usr\".\"Value\" = {value}");
```

First reason is, because I'm reusing that sql query (to be more precise, saving it to audit) and second reason is that I'm aware that `NpgsqlParameter` is also SQL injection safe.

Comment: `FromSqlRaW` uses EF parameter objects, not provider-specific objects. It's *not* a replacement for ADO.NET's DbCommand, it's a method allowing EF to work with raw SQL, for any underlying provider. EF Core will use those parameters to create the provider-specific parameters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm not sure that i understood comment. I have already tried using `SqlParameter` and then i get exception "_The value "value" is not of type "NpgsqlParameter" and cannot be used in this parameter collection_". So the new question  is, is it even possible to use `Parameters` with `Npgsql`?

Comment: `'@value'` is the literal containing 6 characters: "at", "v", "a", "l", "u", "e"; `@value` (no single quotes) means: the value of the parameter named "value"

Comment: @MarcGravell, it works like a charm !! It's confusing because when you use formatable and interpolated strings you need to wrap textual value in single quotes (Postgresql syntax).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I can't check the exact syntax right now - but how about something like:

```cs
    long value = 3;
    var searchParam = new NpgsqlParameter("value", value);
    var _user = _AdminPanelDbContext.User.FromSqlRaw("select * from admin.user as usr where usr.value = @searchParam;", searchParam).FirstOrDefault();
```

There's an end-to-end example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60942020/1657427).

However, sounds like you're using Postgres. If yes, explains why you're seeing the error about needing to use NpgsqlParameter instead of SqlParameter.

Comment: question: why `$"{value}"` instead of just `value` (as the value)? that's OK (although inefficient) for strings, but for non-string types: it stringifies them, which is not necessarily intended

Comment: @MarcGravell you're correct! Was looking at an example which exectued a LIKE condition on the db, E.g. $"%{search_for_me}%"). Have corrected, thx.

Comment: @fuzzy_logic, this is good example and a great thing is that it works !! A small complaint is that i asked question just to avoid inline query in `FromSqlRaw`, but nothing to worry I tried that to and it also works.

Comment: @Genato Great, glad to hear it's working! Your other option is to use [FromSqlInterpolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated?view=efcore-3.1). Especically if you wanted to use string interpolation via $"" syntax. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters) have a good note on when to use each.