# How to check numeric value in linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to translate the following SQL-Select to LINQ to Entities and have a problem with an `isnumeric` check and hope that the community can give me a hint how to resolve it.

```sql
select top(1) column1
from myDataTable with (nolock)
where id = '123456789'
and ISNUMERIC(column1) = 0
```

The tipping point is column1 which is from type `varchar` and can contain either alphanumeric values as well as numeric values.

I tried the following in LINQ to Entities to get the whole row from the table:

```cs
int column1Value;
int paramId = 123456789;
var entry = myDataTable.FirstOrDefault(
x => x.Id == paramId && !(int.TryParse(x.column1, out column1Value))
);
```

In the next step I wanted to check entry for null and then get the value from column1.

But when I debug it, I get the following error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean TryParse(System.String, Int32 ByRef)'.

How can I implement the `isnumeric` check in LINQ?

Comment: I think you can use the [SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric?view=netframework-4.7.2). (Not sure whether you are using EF6 or EF Core)

Comment: Similar question [IsNumeric in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926152/isnumeric-in-ef-core)

Comment: `NOLOCK` is almost always a bug. It doesn't mean go fast, it means read duplicate or dirty data while randomly throwing errors. And maybe corrupt data. The question is slow because of lack of indexes or expressions like `ISNUMERIC(column1) = 0` which prevent the server from using indexes covering the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value1 = (from d in myDataTable 
        where d.id == "123456789"
        && SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(d.column1) == 0
        select d.Column1).FirstOrDefault();
```

`IsNumeric` and, in fact, all of `SqlFunction` exist merely to tell Linq to use the same-named function in SQL.  It's defined like this:

```
[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunction("SqlServer", "ISNUMERIC")]
public static int? IsNumeric (string arg);
```

SqlFunctions defines many other SQL functions you can use, including `CurrentUser`, `DataLength`, `IsDate` and `Checksum`.

You can use the EdmFunctionAttribute on C# methods allow using your user-defined SQL function in LINQ statements.